# Windows 10 INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE SSD Drive After Reset

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10, ssd, sleep

I was happily working away on my machine until I had to go out, I stupidly hit the Sleep button instead of shutdown.

I couldn't get the machine to come out of sleep so ended up having to hit the power button to shutdown.

Now the machine will not boot and reports INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE and I'm locked into a restart / Troubleshoot / repair loop.

Nothing seems to be fixing it and I've tried most of the solutions I've found through google so I've come here in the hope that someone might have an idea.

I would obviously prefer to side step the Reformat -> Win8 -> 8.1 -> 10 upgrade path as that just takes an age.

Anyone that has any tips or pointers that would be great.

Are SSD drives really this fragile?

Comment: Why are you going to install Windows 8, then upgrade that to Windows 8.1 then upgrade that to Windows 10 when all you have to do is install Windows 10?  Just download Media Creation Tool, create a bootable disk, and use that to install Windows 10.  If you decide this problem cannot be fix another way that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue isn't the SSD itself.  Rather, it's how the SSD driver, BIOS, and Windows power management compete and are often misconfigured for low-power states like "sleep".  It's really inexcusable that the vendors haven't figured this out yet.  It's been known for a decade.

As to resolving your problem, you should be able to boot (at least in safe mode) by clearing the current power state.  If your machine is a laptop, remove the battery for a few minutes, put it back, and then try to boot in safe mode (In Win10, the only way to boot to safe mode is from the Troubleshoot screen that you mentioned.  See [How to boot in safe mode in Win10](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/4-ways-boot-safe-mode-windows-10))

If your system is a desktop PC, first try disconnecting the power supply for a few minutes like above.  If that doesn't work, remove the CMOS battery from the motherboard for a few minutes, replace, and try to get into the BIOS.  Reset the settings to the BIOS default, and make sure that the SATA controller (assuming your SSD is on a SATA channel) is set to AHCI and that boot options are set for UEFI boot.

If THAT doesn't work, experiment with the BIOS SATA options for the channel your SSD is connected to until you find the right one.  Usually AHCI default settings are fine, but sometimes the link state power management settings need to be adjusted.  You can also try using  IDE mode, but Windows won't likely like that.

tl;dr: Your SSD is fine.  It's the idiotic software combination between BIOS & Windows10 that screws up sleep.  As you can see from this search, it's a ridiculously frustrating and common problem: [Windows 10 won't boot after sleep](https://www.google.ca/search?q=win10%20can%27t%20boot%20after%20sleep&oq=win10%20can%27t%20boot%20after%20sleep&aqs=chrome..69i57.4659j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: I did actually get this sorted as per the Troubleshoot -> Safe Mode.  Why on earth Windows doesn't do this without intervention if it stays in the Fix - Restart loop I'll never know.

Answer (score 1):

Changed the SATA mode in BIOS from AHCI to compability Mode and that fixed it.

Comment: Welcome to superuser: While this may or may not answer the question,(an answer has been accepted) it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation why your solution works with detail and an easy to follow instructions. If you feel your answer is correct do these things and re-edit. Please take a couple of minutes and read:- http://superuser.com/help .Answering: http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer, again welcome to superuser.Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was changing the SATA mode to AHCI in the BIOS settings.
To do it you should:.

1. Open BIOS Setup(search Google how to do it for your laptop
   or PC model, on mine I had to press F2 during startup).
2. Go to Main settings.
3. Press Ctrl-S so the SATA mode setting will appear.
4. Change it to AHCI
5. Save and exit (F10)